# How to validate HTML tag using Struts 2

Tags: java, html, jsp, validation, struts2

I have one JSP page

```
<form action="passData" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I have action class `UserData.java` with configuration of Struts2

and I use `UserData-validation.xml` for validation

```
<field name="username">
  <field-validator type="requiredstring">
  <message>Name is required</message>           
  </field-validator>
</field>
```

but it is not working if I use

```
<s:textfield name="username"/>
```

It is working properly. But I want to use simple HTML tag.

Comment: Add your Action, add your Struts.xml with InterceptorStack declaration... if `<s:textfield/>` is not working, try to make it works instead of backing to crappy html tags :/ Do you have getter and setter for username in Action ?

Comment: i have get-set for username. if i used <s:textfield/> then validation is working properly but when i used <input type="text" /> then not working

Comment: Ah ok, got it. Then why do you want to use classic HTML tags ? Because you don't like the generated code from the Struts tags ? If so, specify `theme="simple"` in struts.xml, to prevent Struts from generating any code (like labels etc) except the element code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use some Struts2 tags. If you do not want to use `<s:textfield>` tag then use `<s:fielderror>` tag which renders field errors.

Comment: how i can use <s:fielderror> inplace of <input type="text" />

Comment: The `<s:fielderror>` tag just renders field errors if they exists. You need to use it WITH `<input>`.

Comment: ya i understand <s:fielderror/> but i want to call validation.xml without using struts 2 tag. its possible??

Comment: And how you would like to show errors? And why not to use Struts2 tags? They are not evil. ;)

Comment: @RohitR.K. Validation has nothing to do with the tags at all.

Answer (score 0):

The validation works fine on html tags, i.e. `<form` `<input` if the name attribute matches the `fieldName` specified in the `validation.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change conf anything. Just change all Struts `<s:form>` tags to html tag `<form>` and only add `<s:fielderror> </s:fielderror>` in your code. It is perfectly working.